# Getting the wrong answer when executing my code

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, unsupervised-learning

When I execute my code I am getting av_Ein as 0 but the answer(av_Ein) is near to 0.01.
Please help me in finding the mistake.
** Given question**

In these problems, we will explore how Linear Regression for classiﬁcation works. As with the Perceptron Learning Algorithm in Homework # 1, you will create your own target function f and data set D. Take d = 2 so you can visualize the problem, and assume X = [−1,1] × [−1,1] with uniform probability of picking each x ∈ X. In each run, choose a random line in the plane as your target function f (do this by taking two random, uniformly distributed points in [−1,1]×[−1,1] and taking the line passing through them), where one side of the line maps to +1 and the other maps to −1. Choose the inputs xn of the data set as random points (uniformly in X), and evaluate the target function on each xn to get the corresponding output yn.

Take N = 100. Use Linear Regression to ﬁnd g and evaluate Ein, the fraction of in-sample points which got classiﬁed incorrectly. Repeat the experiment 1000 times and take the average (keep the g’s as they will be used again in Problem 6). Which of the following values is closest to the average Ein? (Closest is the option that makes the expression |your answer−given option| closest to 0. Use this deﬁnition of closest here and throughout.

**MY CODE**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
from numpy.linalg import inv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model

av_Ein =0
for P in range(0,1000):
    #Target Line calculation
    line = {}#Target Line
    x1,y1 = np.random.uniform(-1,1,2)
    x2,y2 = np.random.uniform(-1,1,2)
    m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    line['x'] = m
    line['y'] = -1
    line['c'] = y1-m*x1
    X = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(100,2))
    X = np.c_[np.ones(100),X]
    #------
    #Target calculation

    Y =[]#Target
    for i in range(0,100):
        Y.append(line['c']*1+line['x']*X[i][1]+line['y']*X[i][2])

    #------
    #For calculating the weight function W = pseudoinverse(X) x Y

    X_tran = X.transpose()
    temp_1 = np.matmul(X_tran,X)
    temp_inv = inv(temp_1)
    temp_1 = np.matmul(temp_inv,X_tran)
    W = np.matmul(temp_1,Y)

    #end of calculation

    #E_in(insample error) claculation for this final hypothesis

    E_in=0#(No of times the final hypothesis not matching with target /len(Target))

    #No of misclassified insample points

    for k in range(0,100):
        if np.sign(X[k][0]*W[0]+X[k][1]*W[1]+X[k][2]*W[2]) != np.sign(Y[k]):
            E_in = E_in+1
        #E_in = E_in+math.pow((lm.predict([X[k]])-Y[k]),2)

    #---

    E_in = E_in/100#E_in calculation
    av_Ein = av_Ein+E_in

av_Ein = av_Ein/1000 #(AVg of all the insmple error)
print(av_Ein)
```

Comment: You start of with `E_in` as an integer, but when you get to `E_in = E_in/100` I imagine you're expecting it to be a `float`.

Comment: @quamrana E_in is error in input sample it is nothing but probability of misclassifications in the input sample

Comment: After doing linear regression we are finding how it is holding up with the input sample according to my codes output every point is being classified correctly.